# NoSuchMethodException <init>() when extending javafx.scene.chart.LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to extend `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` in order to add some extra features.

I have implemented the two constructors

`public LiveLineChart(Timeline animation, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis)`

and

`public LiveLineChart(Timeline animation, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis, ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> data)`

My project compiles, however, when I run, I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mypackage.LiveLineChart.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
... 20 more
```

If I try to implement a default (empty) constructor, I get a compile error:

```
no suitable constructor found for LineChart(no arguments)
constructor LineChart.LineChart(Axis<Number>,Axis<Number>) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor LineChart.LineChart(Axis<Number>,Axis<Number>,ObservableList<Series<Number,Number>>) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What am I missing to be able to get this to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LineChart` has no default constructor, so you need to invoke one of the constructors that it declares explicitly from a constructor you define. Looking at the constructors you've said you declared, you probably need something like this:

```
public LiveLineChart(Timeline animation, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis) {
    super(xAxis, yAxis);
    // ...
}

public LiveLineChart(Timeline animation, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis, ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> data) {
    super(xAxis, yAxis, data) ;
    // ...
}
```

If you want to be able to create a `LiveLineChart` from `FXML`, you either need a no-argument constructor, or a builder class. A no-argument constructor will not leave you any mechanism to initialize the axes (since they are managed by your superclass and are immutable, i.e. there is no way to set them once the superclass constructor has been invoked). So you most likely need to define the following:

```
public class LiveLineChartBuilder {
    private Axis<Number> xAxis ;
    private Axis<Number> yAxis ;
    private Timeline animation ;
    private ObservableList<Series<Number,Number>> data ;

    public static LiveLineChartBuilder create() {
        return new LiveLineChartBuilder();
    }

    public LiveLineChartBuilder xAxis(Axis<Number> xAxis) {
        this.xAxis = xAxis ;
        return this ;
    }

    public LiveLineChartBuilder yAxis(Axis<Number> yAxis) {
        this.yAxis = yAxis ;
        return this ;
    }

    public LiveLineChartBuilder animation(Timeline animation) {
        this.animation = animation ;
        return this ;
    }

    public LiveLineChartBuilder data(Series<Number, Number> data) {
        this.data = data ;
        return this ;
    }

    public LiveLineChart build() {
        // if else may not be necessary, depending on how you define constructors in LiveLineChart
        if (data == null) {
            return new LiveLineChart(animation, xAxis, yAxis);
        } else {
            return new LiveLineChart(animation, xAxis, yAxis, data);
        }
    }
}
```

This will enable you to do

```
<LiveLineChart>
<xAxis><NumberAxis><!-- ... --></NumberAxis></xAxis>
<!-- etc -->
</LiveLineChart>
```

in your FXML.

Comment: This all looks good, but then how do I actually USE the builder?

Comment: You don't. The FXMLLoader automatically uses it if the associated class has no default constructor. (It matches class X by classname to an XBuilder.)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no default constructor in `LineChart` and you need to call one of the base class's constructors explicitly or use constructor chaining:

```
public LiveLineChart() {
    super(new ValueAxis<Number>(), new ValueAxis<Number>()); // use LineChart.LineChart(Axis<Number>,Axis<Number>)
    // do further initialisation
}
```

or

```
public LiveLineChart() {
    this(new ValueAxis<Number>(), new ValueAxis<Number>()); // use LiveLineChart(Timeline animation, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis)
    // do further initialisation
}
```

Of course you can use any other axis type instead of `ValueAxis` too.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured that much out already. The problem now is that while I can now compile, I seem to have a problem loading it via FXML declaration, and now get the following error:

    Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "xAxis" does not exist or is read-only.

My xAxis property is defined in LiveLineChart is defined as follows: @FXML public NumberAxis xAxis;

Comment: You have to initialize the axes in the superclass constructor; so a no-argument constructor probably won't work here. In order to do this, you'll need a builder class so the `FXMLLoader` can instantiate your class. See alternative answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I will use answer block.
I have never worked with javafx but this is simple java issue.
Have you defined default constructor in the second approach? Looks like its missing. Class loader needs default constructor (with no parameters)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... as stated above, when I attempt to add a default, no-args constructor I get the compile error mentioned above. It seems to be saying that the class I'm trying to extend doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: Yes, its trying to tell you that LineChart has no default constructor. You are adding default constructor to subclass (your class)?From your default constructor you will have to call super with appropriate parameters.