# Quadrant Scatter Chart in JavaFX?

Tags: java, charts, javafx-8, scatter

thanks for reading my question.

I'm currently working with JavaFX-8, SceneBuilder and Eclipse.

I want to do a scatter chart with four quadrants, that has two fixed number axis (the data position is not relevant, I only need to display the dots on each quadrant... only matters in which quadrant a dot is). Each quadrant must have a background with a specific color.

I found [this question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3597286?sr=stream&ru=2733953), so I tried to extend ScatterChart with the aim of overriding the method *layoutPlotChildren()*. I tried a minimum implementation to see if it will run with my FXML (I did import the new component to the FXML). This was my minimum implementation:

```
public class ScatterQuadrantChart<X,Y> extends ScatterChart<X,Y> {
  public ScatterQuadrantChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
      super(xAxis, yAxis);
} }
```

And then, I get the **NotSuchMethodError init** error. I found a similar error but from someone extending LineChart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454936/nosuchmethodexception-init-when-extending-javafx-scene-chart-linechart), but I'm not quite sure of what I need to do on my own class.

I tried adding a no-parameters constructor, but I need to call super and cant because I can't call the "getXAxis()" method either. *What should I do here?*

Plus, the other issue that remains is, once I solve this, *what should the layoutPlotChildren() method do?*

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is arising because the default mechanism for the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate a class is to call the no-argument constructor. Your `ScatterQuadrantChart` has no no-argument constructor, hence the `NoSuchMethodError`.

Prior to Java 8, the only way to fix this was to create a builder class for your class, as in the post you linked. JavaFX 8 introduced (but failed to document) a mechanism to specify values for constructor parameters that would be recognized by the `FXMLLoader`, using the `@NamedArg` annotation).

So, in Java 8, you can modify your `ScatterQuadrantChart`:

```
public class ScatterQuadrantChart<X,Y> extends ScatterChart<X,Y> {
  public ScatterQuadrantChart(@NamedArg("xAxis")Axis<X> xAxis, 
         @NamedArg("yAxis)Axis<Y> yAxis) {
      super(xAxis, yAxis);
  } 
}
```

and then your FXML will look like

```
<ScatterQuadrantChart>
    <xAxis>
        <NumberAxis ... />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis ... />
    </yAxis>
</ScatterQuadrantChart>
```

I have no idea if or how SceneBuilder will interact with this, but the FXML will work.

As for the implementation, you will need to add some nodes to the plot to represent your quadrants. I would probably just use plain regions for these. Create them in the constructor and call `getPlotChildren().add(...)` to add them. Then in the `layoutPlotChildren()` method, first call the superclass method (which will lay out the scatter chart nodes), and then resize and reposition the quadrants. You can use `getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(...)` to figure out the location from the actual divider value.

In real life, you should add style classes to the quadrants so you can style them externally with css, etc, but a very basic implementation might look like

```
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class ScatterQuadrantChart<X,Y> extends ScatterChart<X,Y> {

    private final Property<X> xQuadrantDivider = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final Property<Y> yQuadrantDivider = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final Region nwQuad ;
    private final Region neQuad ;
    private final Region swQuad ;
    private final Region seQuad ;

    public ScatterQuadrantChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, 
            @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
        nwQuad = new Region();
        neQuad = new Region();
        swQuad = new Region();
        seQuad = new Region();
        nwQuad.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightsalmon ;");
        neQuad.setStyle("-fx-background-color: antiquewhite ;");
        swQuad.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aqua ;");
        seQuad.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightskyblue ;");
        getPlotChildren().addAll(nwQuad, neQuad, swQuad, seQuad);

        ChangeListener<Object> quadListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutPlotChildren();
        xQuadrantDivider.addListener(quadListener);
        yQuadrantDivider.addListener(quadListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutPlotChildren() {
        super.layoutPlotChildren();
        X x = xQuadrantDivider.getValue();
        Y y = yQuadrantDivider.getValue();
        if (x != null && y != null) {
            Axis<X> xAxis = getXAxis();
            Axis<Y> yAxis = getYAxis();
            double xPixels = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(x);
            double yPixels = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(y);
            double totalWidth = xAxis.getWidth();
            double totalHeight = yAxis.getHeight();
            nwQuad.resizeRelocate(0, 0, xPixels, yPixels);
            swQuad.resizeRelocate(0, yPixels, xPixels, totalHeight - yPixels);
            neQuad.resizeRelocate(xPixels, 0, totalWidth - xPixels, yPixels);
            seQuad.resizeRelocate(xPixels, yPixels, totalWidth - xPixels, totalHeight - yPixels);
        }
    }

    public final Property<X> xQuadrantDividerProperty() {
        return this.xQuadrantDivider;
    }

    public final X getXQuadrantDivider() {
        return this.xQuadrantDividerProperty().getValue();
    }

    public final void setXQuadrantDivider(final X xQuadrantDivider) {
        this.xQuadrantDividerProperty().setValue(xQuadrantDivider);
    }

    public final Property<Y> yQuadrantDividerProperty() {
        return this.yQuadrantDivider;
    }

    public final Y getYQuadrantDivider() {
        return this.yQuadrantDividerProperty().getValue();
    }

    public final void setYQuadrantDivider(final Y yQuadrantDivider) {
        this.yQuadrantDividerProperty().setValue(yQuadrantDivider);
    }


}
```

Test code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScatterQuadrantChartTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final Random rng = new Random();

        ScatterQuadrantChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterQuadrantChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(rng.nextDouble() * 100, rng.nextDouble() * 100));
        }
        chart.getData().add(series);

        chart.setXQuadrantDivider(50);
        chart.setYQuadrantDivider(50);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @James_D! The FXML works, it loads perfectly with no error. The problem I have now is the second question: "How to implement the "layoutPlotChildren" to plot the colored background?

Comment: Updated answer with a sample implementation.

Comment: Thanks again @James_D! I tried the code but the quadrants are not visibles. I tried the code as-is before setting the style-classes, and removed the CSS I had that changed the dots-shapes to avoid issues. Nevertheless, the regions are not visible. I tried replacing the colors for the HEX code, but they are still transparent.

Comment: Make sure you set the `xQuadrantDivider` and `yQuadrantDivider` values. I updated with test code.

Comment: it works like a charm!! Will tune it to put the style, thank you!! :D